# How to "Remove query string from external resources" in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to boost speed. I tested on [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/) and got the following results:

[image]

There are some plugins for this in Wordpress, but I don't know how to do it in ROR.

Do you know what it means and how I can achieve this in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: It seems it's the call to your assets, see `css?body...`, although the application won't work correctly, try removing those specifics assets, the ones which appears there and try again, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

This is to indicate to Sprockets that the version of the file to retrieve is the non-precompiled version for debugging.

You can get rid of that in your config/environments/development.rb or production.rb or *your_environment.rb* with:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

This option is true by default in the development environment, so I guess you are testing in that mode.